# Python for-loop/while/if/open-file auto completion in Vim

Tags: python, vim, vi

Perl and C/C++  have perl-support.vim and c.vim by Fritz Mehner
http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=169

that support a very convenient auto completion shortcut in visual mode 
(e.g \aw for While construct or \ai for if else construct).

Does anybody know if such a comprehensive scripts
also exist for Python?

python.vim doesn't seem to suppor this kind
of auto completion.

Answer (score 1):

Autocompletion is *automatic*: it happens without you doing anything.

What you want is not "autocompletion" but it can be achieved with varying levels of usefulness in a multitude of ways: insert mode mappings, abbreviations or full blown snippet expansion plugins like snipmate ([abandoned original](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim), [maintained fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)) or [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips).

I recommend the later option. This is a snipmate snippet:

```
# For
snippet for
    for ${1:item} in ${2:items}:
        ${3:code...}
```

When you type `for<Tab>`, the snippet is expanded to:

```
for [item] in items:
    code...
```

`item` is highlighted, ready to be changed to whatever you want and further `<Tab>`s jump you to `items` and `code...`:

```
for foo in [items]:
    code...

for foo in bar:
    [code...]

for foo in bar:
    print foo
```

This is by far the most flexible option.